# Output EE template tags in a channel entry field?

Tags: templates, tags, devdemon-forms

I have a form I've created using DevDemon's 'Forms' module. To embed the form, it looks like I need to use `{exp:forms:form form_name="my_survey"}`.

I want to embed this form into a blog post on the Blog channel we have. So I added the tag in to the body of the blog post field (a rich text field).

It seems EE just outputs the string {exp:forms:form form_name="outlook_survey"} rather than actually parsing the tags. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Allows ExpressionEngine code to be used in entries and then parsed in
>   the template. Currently, you cannot put EE tags into an entry/post and
>   have them rendered in the template. Instead, the code itself will just
>   display, unprocessed. This plugin makes it so any EE tags in an entry
>   will actually be parsed and have results outputted.

[Allow EE Code](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code) by EllisLab